Issue with Sprite not showing up, using Pygame
I'm following a begginner tutorial to start using pygame, but I'm stuck with the sprite display. I'm not able to make it visible on screen, please find below the code related to the sprite.
I'm not able to find where I mess up, do you have any idea ?
My Sprite is "Projectile" and is defined in Projectile Class, it is sent by the player, so I added a "launch_projectile" method, and in main it should be displaying the projectiles
Projectile class
import pygame

# Définir la classe projectile
class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

# Définir le constructeur de la classe
def __init__(self, player):
    super().__init__()
    self.velocity = 5
    self.image = pygame.image.load('Assets\Blast.png')
    #self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (50, 50))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = player.rect.x + 100
    self.rect.y = player.rect.y

Player class
import pygame
from projectile import Projectile

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.health = 100
    self.max_health = 100
    self.attack = 10
    self.velocity = 1
    self.all_projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.image = pygame.image.load('Assets\Flying_Raccoon.png')
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (100, 100))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = 0
    self.rect.y = 0

# Créer un nouveau Projectile
def launch_projectile(self):
    self.all_projectiles.add(Projectile(self))

### Méthodes de déplacement (X / Y) ###
def move_right(self):
    self.rect.x += self.velocity

def move_left(self):
    self.rect.x -= self.velocity

def move_up(self):
    self.rect.y -= self.velocity

def move_down(self):
    self.rect.y += self.velocity

Game
import pygame
from player import Player

class Game:
def __init__(self):
    #Générer le joueur à la création du jeu
    self.player = Player()
    self.pressed = {}

Main
import pygame
from game import Game
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Pilot Raccoon")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080,720))

#Charger arrière plan
background = pygame.image.load('Assets\Bg.jpg')

#Charger le jeu
game = Game()

running = True

#Boucle du jeu
while running:

#Mettre à jour l'écran
pygame.display.flip()

# Afficher le background
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
# Afficher le joueur
screen.blit(game.player.image, game.player.rect)
# Afficher les projectiles
game.player.all_projectiles.draw(screen)


# Déplacement du joueur
if game.pressed.get(pygame.K_RIGHT) and game.player.rect.x + game.player.rect.width < screen.get_width():
    game.player.move_right()
elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_LEFT) and game.player.rect.x > 0:
    game.player.move_left()
elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_UP) and game.player.rect.y > 0:
    game.player.move_up()
elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_DOWN) and game.player.rect.y + game.player.rect.height < screen.get_height():
    game.player.move_down()


for event in pygame.event.get():
    
    # Evenement de fermeture de la fenêtre
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    # Détecter la touche enfoncée
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        game.pressed[event.key] = True

        # Détecter si la touche espace est enfoncée
        if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
            game.player.launch_projectile()

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            game.pressed[event.key] = False

    

pygame.quit()
→ Edited with full code
EDIT 02 with answer :
In Main, to launch projectile if spacebar on press, code was :
    ...            
    # Détecter la touche enfoncée
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        game.pressed[event.key] = True

        # Détecter si la touche espace est enfoncée
        if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
            game.player.launch_projectile()

In the condition above, the ".type" should be replaced by ".key" :
    ...              
    # Détecter la touche enfoncée
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        game.pressed[event.key] = True

        # Détecter si la touche espace est enfoncée
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            game.player.launch_projectile()


Could you post your whole code because it looks like there are a lot of errors? One important thing to ensure that images are displayed on the screen is to add pygame.display.update() at the end of the while loop.

Sure, just edited with the full code, I understood that pygame.display.flip() was also to updated the screen

In your main file you used:
if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
    game.player.launch_projectile()

However, the "event.type" is just "pygame.KEYDOWN" and not "pygame.K_SPACE". You  should use "game.pressed.get(pygame.K_SPACE)" instead:
if game.pressed.get(pygame.K_SPACE):
    game.player.launch_projectile()


Ah ok, in fact to avoid having infinite projectiles if we stay on spacebar down, the guy was using event.KEY == pygame.K_SPACE: but I red it wrong several time, putting event.TYPE.
Thanks for highlighting this which helps me to solve, I will edit with the answer.
